# How can I make an AverTv tuner work?

Tags: 11.04, tv, tvtime

I have a PC with AVerMedia **AVerTV Super 007**. I have been so far unsuccessful in making it work. Could anyone help me?

#### Specs:

- Intel pentium 4
- 2gb DDR1
- Ubuntu 11.04
- Latest updates

Comment: I recommend you check out the new ROBOLINUX Distro which is based on Ubuntu. It comes with several DE options. My Avermedia USB Card works automatically, straight out of the box. Evidently the requisite drivers come preinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular card exists in two varieties - if you have the "super hybrid" version you are out of luck - there is "experimental" support for the "hybrid" variant.

To get this card to work you'll need to grab to extract the firmware from a Windows DLL - see this [wiki page for further information](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia_AVerTV_DVB-T_Super_007).

I couldn't myself find the firmware from the link - you might have to grab the dll from your Windows card install disk and extract it using the perl script described on the wiki.

Once you've got the firmware, save it as `/lib/firmware/dvb-fe-tda10046.fw`

If you are lucky, after a reboot your card should be recognised.

This wiki page is dated Jan 2010 - if however, the "experimental" support hasn't yet made it into the Natty kernel, you need to download drivers from the linked repositories and compile & install them yourself.

Comment: This is probably correct

Answer (score 2):

This is a daring claim, but the drivers to *my* TV adaptor were in the nonfree firmware package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: It dosent work in my system